# Publish on GooglePlay using Android Studio 3.0 (Beta Version),Is there any probability or chance to arise Compatibility issue on App

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, jcenter

I am always very excited to work on New Platform/New Release Dependencies Gradle/Android Studio.
But I am more concern about publishing APK to PlayStore as Statble Mode. 
We have large number of Android Subcribed Users and 
app must be functioning as per expected outcome means app should always work smoothly on Various manfucturing devices/versions/resolution.
Off curse, it must be bug free and it should not crashing.
Please see the attached snap exactly what I doing.

Even I have gone through release note, It is recommending '**Android Studio v2.3.0**'
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html
But I am currently experimenting on '**Android Studio v3.0.0 Beta 6**' for learn new functions/libraries.

I am will be very glad and thankful if somebody will help to clear my concern. Thank You.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it is slightly hard understanding, but from what I got you're asking whether or not apps made in AS beta x will work on devices given compatibility and instability in the IDE. (if I'm wrong, leave a comment).

APK's made in beta versions of Android Studio work just as well as if they were made in a stable version. The beta versions are experimental versions, but if you can't sign APK's that can be used no one would use the beta versions. So if you have an APK signed in AS beta x, it can still be used on devices

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
Yeah, You have understand properly what I want to clarify. Thank you for updates.